# NextJS 13 - Rendering as Text not HTML

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, cosmicjs

I am trying to figure out why the HTML text that is in my CosmicJS CMS is rendering on the page as text.

Here is the function to get the post.

```
export async function getPost() {

    const data = await Promise.resolve(
      cosmicClient.objects
        .findOne({
          type: 'posts',
          slug: 'first-90-days-as-cio'
        })
    );

    const post: Post = await data.object;


    return post;
}
```

Here is the code that calls the function, gets the post, and then displays the content.

```
async function Post() {
   
    let post = await getPost();

    return (
        <>
          <div className="mobile:w-full tablet:w-3/5  items-center">
                            <h2 className="text-primary text-center mobile:text-2xl tablet:text-3xl px-14 py-5">
                                {post?.title}
                            </h2>
                            <p className="text-black px-10 font-light text-justify">
                                {post?.metadata.content}
                            </p>
                        </div>
        </>
    );
```

Here is what the text looks like rendered on the page...

[image]

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop

```
<p className="text-black px-10 font-light text-justify" 
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post?.metadata.content }}/>
```

Comment: @Don I would suggest that you use an external library to parse html string for extra security